# Site Permissions AD Query

Tags: 2010, security, active-directory

When assigning permissions to a site in Sharepoint 2010, is it possible instead of specifically adding a group or a user, to create an LDAP query or something simular.

For example I have a group called; SharepointContribute, ITStaff.

If a user is a member of both these groups they should be able to contribute to the IT site.

Answer (score 1):

You can add AD Security groups (not distribution lists) as members in SharePoint groups.  Add those 2 AD groups to your Contribute Sharepoint group and those users in the group will have that level of permission.

Comment: The two examples I gave above where both Security Groups, but what I am looking for is to only grant permission to a user which has both of those groups, not either or. I am trying to avoid creating many subgroups in AD, i.e. ITContribute, AdminContribute and just leverage the groups I already have.

Comment: No, that is not possible.